# Azure ARM template - vnet example

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am new to Azure.  I am trying to create an environment that *should* be fairly straightforward - App Service and Azure SQL with a Private Endpoint.  I decided to try this ARM template:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/web-app-regional-vnet-private-endpoint-sql-storage/
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/web-app-regional-vnet-private-endpoint-sql-storage

I am not quite sure what to put for the `V Nets` (sic) entry.  I have tried for hours and read through all the documentation I can find, which is lacking. Can someone please provide advice or an example.  Thanks.

Azure Image

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is what I ended up putting in the VNets parameter:

```
[{"name":"hub-vnet","addressPrefixes":["10.1.0.0/16"],"subnets":[{"name":"PrivateLinkSubnet","addressPrefix":"10.1.1.0/24","udrName":null,"nsgName":null,"delegations":null,"privateEndpointNetworkPolicies":"Disabled","privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies":"Enabled"}]},{"name":"spoke-vnet","addressPrefixes":["10.2.0.0/16"],"subnets":[{"name":"AppSvcSubnet","addressPrefix":"10.2.1.0/24","udrName":null,"nsgName":null,"privateEndpointNetworkPolicies":"Enabled","privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies":"Enabled","delegations":[{"name":"appservice","properties":{"serviceName":"Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"}}]}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same repo, check out the [azuredeploy.parameters.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/demos/web-app-regional-vnet-private-endpoint-sql-storage/azuredeploy.parameters.json) file, and you'll see an example of the `vNets` object it's looking for.

You can use the parameters file as-is and deploy it to your subscription or feel free to customize the names, address spaces, etc. by adjusting the properties

### snippet

```
"parameters": {
    "vNets": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "hub-vnet",
                // ...
            },
            {
                "name": "spoke-vnet",
                // ...
            }
        ]
    },
```